# TypeError: instance.render is not a function (finishClassComponent)

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js. I create a project with "create-react-app". I am following docs. But I got this error. Here is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Board/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Board` component is missing `render()` function.

Change

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }
}
```

to

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Square value={"someValue"} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shoin thanks for answer. I copied components from doc. is "render" have to be always in components?

Comment: correct, in stateful components (the ones that `extends React.Component`), you must have `render()` function